# Infinity Downslope Influence with TauDEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, taudem

Does anybody now how to calculate Infinity Downslope Influence with the TauDEM version?

the command was present until version 3.x but now disappeared I don't know if it was renamed or simply removed.

Answer (score 3):

Downslope Influence is the same as weighted contributing area with weight values equal to 1 in the influence zone and 0 elsewhere.  It can thus be evaluated using TauDEM D-Infinity Contributing Area.

e.g. AreaDinf -ang < angfile > -sca < scafile> -wg , where wgfile is a grid with values of 1 in your influence zone and 0 elsewhere.  The result is written to scafile (even though once a weight grid is used, it is no longer specific catchment area).

Given that this is a special case of weighted contributing area, I decided to not carry the burden of maintaining a separately named GUI function, and removed the GUI for Downslope Influence for later versions of TauDEM, that had internally used AreaDinf code.

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange. Your notable experience an knowledge on hydrological modelling is most welcome.